# Why there's a Connect Timeout in SQL Server? I just made two tests and the connection fails instantly, no matter what

Tags: .net, sql-server

I made two tests, using .NET to connect to Sql Server:

1. I tried to connect to a local server which is on but the specified database does not exist. In this case it triggers a `SqlException` with error number `4060` (cannot login with the specified user)
2. I tried to connect to a local server which process is stopped. In this case it triggers an   `SqlException` with error number `-1` (A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server).

In both cases it fails instantly, even though I specified 20 seconds in the connection string. In what situations will it wait the time I told it to wait?

Comment: There may be for but one of the reasons would be waiting whilst trying to get a connection out of a connection pool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you've managed to *connect* - it's not like you're waiting for the network - but you've got authentication or authorization problems. I wouldn't *expect* that to be part of a connection timeout. The purpose of a connection timeout is to handle network congestion - not to delay authentication failures.

EDIT: For the second case, the machine would presumably be actively refusing the connection. Again, that's not network congestion - it's not the kind of thing that connection timeouts are meant to handle.

Comment: I agree to you, but why the test 2 would fail instantly?

Comment: @AndréPena: In that case I suspect it's got a "connection refused" which again isn't the same as "it's taking a long time to connect". Again, it's not something to do with network congestion - it's the machine saying "you can't connect".

Answer (score 1):

It will only wait for the timeout to occur if it reaches that amount of time **without encountering a "permanent" error**. Why would it wait longer to report the issue?

Where it's likely to kick in is if the network infrastructure is slow - it may take several retires.